# A word for someone who does not keep up with popular culture

Tags: phrase-requests, pejorative-language

Person *A* does not keep up with celebrities or popular entertainment. *A* knows that they exist, so I don't think *sheltered* is the right word.

Also, would it be a different word if *A* tried to forced herself to learn it?

Comment: they who ? learn what ? It's hard to get what you mean even for a non-native like me :-)

Comment: An *introvert* would seem much like what you described. Or she might suffer from chronic depression or some sort of mental issues! It's difficult to say without knowing *why* she doesn't act like the majority or people.

Comment: @Nate She doesn't because she like it.

Comment: @Pam _they_ is referring to the celebrities and popular entertainment

Comment: Then "introvert" might be your word. An introvert is not usually very sociable because she cares more about developing her cogitative faculties and growing stronger inside rather than fitting better in her surrounding community. She is the opposite of an *outgoing* person, that is a person who enjoys meeting new people, talking to them, spending her time with them, etc. More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraversion_and_introversion

Comment: You mean people who have an actual life then?  Words like *fad-proof* come to mind.

Comment: *Fluff-avoiders? Substance-seekers?*

Comment: Can we coin them the AthomSferes? I never know who is who anymore or whats going on. Heck, apparently there was a new Star Trek movie and I missed it!

Comment: If I wanted to speak positively of such a person (which I would), I would call him or her a "non-ephemeralist"—that is, a person who doesn't keep up with things of no lasting significance. I believe I've heard such people referred to as having "a low pop-culture IQ," which is a rather astonishing twist on the idea of IQ, when you think about it.

Comment: This person who doesn't keep up with gossip news, the latest news on celebrities etc. Is it because this person doesn't care / is uninterested in those things / is always bored / thinks "pop-culture" is a waste of time / has a full active life / prefers reading (for example) / doesn't own a TV / doesn't socialize etc. If you can tell us why, then we can give you the best possible answer.

Comment: ‘Living under a rock’ is a notion often associated by such people, whether fairly or not.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that's a good one, I had forgotten that. You should post it.

Comment: "Comedian Tig Notaro struggles to guess the identity of a celebrity guest, made difficult by the little pop culture she consumes and her inability to recognize celebrity faces." – [Under a Rock with Tig Notaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_a_Rock_with_Tig_Notaro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to frame it more in a more affirmative sense of what the individual *does* embrace, rather than what he or she does not, you could use "elitist" or "aesthete" or perhaps even "philocalist" (OED " A lover of beautiful things.") - all of which convey a sense of fine discrimination. Perhaps that person might be a "paragon" (OED - "A person of outstanding merit; a person who serves as a model of some quality") because they transcend such petty temptations.

Comment: "Paragon" is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

While something could certainly be constructed that would make sense to mean what you want, I think it's important to keep in mind the context of when such a phrase would be used. It sounds like you want something to use in everyday social conversation, which means that the answer must not only work but already be in common usage. I like "non-ephemeralist" from the comments, but it's not something that people actually say, so you'd have to follow it up by explaining what you mean in a lengthier form anyway.

I don't think there really is a specific word that fits. I might say something like "I don't follow pop culture," but that's probably overly broad - I do, for instance, follow the worlds of music and video games, which are certainly part of pop culture. You'd have to be more specific - "I don't follow celebrity gossip." Or, as a sort of metonymy, "I don't read tabloids."

Answer (score 1):

I would call them an individualist, free-thinkers, or someone who marches to the beat of their own drum. They are not shackled by the pop culture dogma that surrounds us in everyday life, which is constantly trying to tell us what we should be liking or is worth spending our time, energy, or money on. They may occasionally like the same things that are considered pop culture, but it is purely because their tastes happen to coincide and not because they actually follow trends or the mainstream ideas of what is "in".

They are people who have grasped the best of their own freedom to like whatever they want and lack the concern for other people's opinions that often drives us to watch, listen, or buy just because everyone else is. They are often the innovators who come up with new ideas because they are venturing into ideas or passions different from what is popular now. They are the ones who will start tomorrow's trends.

Comment: Please provide concise explanations based on facts (provide research) and not subjective views.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these are spoken slang:

- square
- daggy (http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Daggy)
- [uncool](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uncool)
- [untrendy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/untrendy)
- [out of fashion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_fashion)/style/trend/  (*That just proves once more that he is so out of style. He needs to get with the age. Even Ashanti isn't in, anymore.*)
- [old-fashioned](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/Old-fashioned)
- not in fashion   (*Pink is so not in fashion! DUH! / Why are you wearing white shoes, they are so not in fashion.*)
- not in  (*She is so not in. / Even Ashanti isn't in, anymore.*)

=================================================================

Edit:

I'm sorry, I've only now realized you're not looking for a judgmental term, but for something complimentary. Someone's already come up with "fad-proof", and that gave me this idea:

- **fad-free**

I construe it as a pun on *fat-free*. It might perhaps still be seen as derogatory, but this time not as directed toward you, but rather extending *from* you. There's a blog with that word:

[100percentfadfree](http://100percentfadfree.blogspot.com/)

> According to the mass media, the current fads are all about being half-naked... but you don't have to sell your soul to be fashionable and look cute! Don't let anyone tell you that modesty is boring... or ugly, frumpy, dumpy, drab, or dull. Modesty is all about beauty. It is classic, timeless, and **fad-free**.

Comment: Not *necessarily* the OP is looking for a positive expression. It is the users of this community who think "A" ought to be applauded, and have suggested complimentary terms. The OP's friend could very well be "out-of-touch" (for example) or "uncool. It's not clear from the OP's description.

Answer (score -2):

Anyway, some wild guesses following the question title, might be:

*unfashionable, unstylish*

or maybe *reserved, discrete*, if you mean someone introvert

Comment: I did not down vote you but your answer is off the mark. The person in question is not "informed" about the world of celebrities, what is often referred to as "cronaca rosa" or "pettegolezzi" (gossip)  in Italian. This question has nothing to do with clothes or fashion as such. You can be an introvert and still watch television and read glam mags, so that doesn't cover it either. You could, perhaps, call her "not frivolous" or something along those lines.

Comment: "Popular culture" (I was referring to title, as the question content was not clear to me when first put down) should not be made of gossip only. It also includes other aspects.